# How can I check if specific applications are open prior to silently installing a program?

Tags: windows-xp, script, installer, windows-installer

(Sorry in advance if this is a duplicate question.  I did search and didn't find anything).

Windows XP

I want to script an MSI installer to run silently (via msiexec).  A prerequisite step is that certain applications (most notably Office and IE) need to be closed/shutdown prior to the installer running.  How can I check to see if applications are open and close them if necessary?

Comment: I know this is horrible, but you could write a batch script to do `taskkill /im "processname"`.

Comment: @TheElectricMuffin That might work although errors come up if it doesn't find the program.

Answer (score -2):

Open Task Manager & that'll show all currently running applications & processes.

Typing Task Manager into XP’s help menu will give a option to start Task Manager.

To avoid possible errors, Close each application via each applications menu. Only close an application via Task Manager if a particular application refuses to close via its application menu.

Comment: The question clearly refers to a programmatic way to detect and terminate processes, so this answer doesn't help.

Comment: It'll list all open apps to help decide which to close down. Personal experience taught me this.